# Flutter ListTile left alignment

Tags: flutter

I am having a textfield and two ListTile . My problem is that ListTile icon is not left aligned. ListTile Icon must come in alignemnt of textfield.

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Alarm'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Watch'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.watch),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Alarm'),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        leading: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: const Text('Watch'),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        leading: Icon(Icons.watch),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

add line

contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0)

I hope, This might help you :))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code see [**`ListTile`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(),
        ListTile(
          dense: true,
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          title: const Text('Alarm'),
          leading: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        ),
        ListTile(
          dense: true,
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(vertical: -4),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          title: const Text('Watch'),
          leading: Icon(Icons.watch),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Result-> [image]